# Alignment in \oneof from the phonrule package

Tags: phonology, latex

This question piggybacks off of [the question/answer here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/is-there-a-package-for-formatting-phonological-rules-in-latex?newreg=2ff4e6ce61b34f2cb83ccb8936ee24bd), where one answer mentions how to create a phonological rule using the `phonrule` package.

MWE here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,onecolumn]{memoir}

\usepackage{phonrule}

\begin{document}

\phon{x}{\oneof{
\envr{w}{z} \\
\envl{v}{\phonfeat{
+feature x \\
-feature y}}}}

\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image]

You can see that output and environments are centered.  Is there any way to un-center them and/or left-align them?  The centering that it does appears to be an intentional addition in v1.2.0 of `phonrule`.  But there is nothing else in the documentation regarding alignment.

I need it to be the standard left-aligned version - that is, left-aligned output *and* left-aligned environment.  Something like this (exact spacing is flexible):

[image]

Trying to throw in any type of alignment generally breaks the `phonrule` environment and it won't compile *or* it aligns the entire figure/example, rather than just the individual (output + environment) sections.

I have been using roughly the same as the other answer from the above question which utilizes `\mbox`.  This is fine, but adding  additional outputs and environments is either messy or requires a new command based on the differences.  `phonrule` generally does all this in a much cleaner and more expandable way, which is why I'm looking into being able to modify the alignment.

Comment: I suggest asking this question on the TeX stackexchange http://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Will do.  Thought I'd trying in the same sub (linguistics) as that other question first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this can be found over at [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342163/alignment-in-oneof-from-the-phonrule-package).  The accepted answer from egreg is repeated here, for future convenience.

> Here's a complete reimplementation of `phonrule`:
>
> ```
> \documentclass{article}
>
> \providecommand*{\textrightarrow}{\ensuremath{\rightarrow}}
> \providecommand*{\textplus}{\ensuremath{+}}
> \providecommand*{\textminus}{\ensuremath{-}}
>
> \newcommand*{\phold}{\rule[-1.5pt]{1.5ex}{.5pt}}
>
> \newcommand*{\phon}[2]{#1 \textrightarrow{} #2}
> \newcommand*{\phonc}[3]{\phon{#1}{#2}~/~#3}
> \newcommand*{\phonr}[3]{\phon{#1}{#2}~/~\phold#3}
> \newcommand*{\phonl}[3]{\phon{#1}{#2}~/~#3\phold}
> \newcommand*{\phonb}[4]{\phonl{#1}{#2}{#3}#4}
>
> \makeatletter
> \newcommand*{\env}{\@ifstar{\@env{&}}{\@env{~}}}
> \newcommand*{\@env}[3]{#2~/#1#3}
>
> \newcommand*{\envr}{\@ifstar{\@envr{&}}{\@envr{~}}}
> \newcommand*{\@envr}[3]{\@env{#1}{#2}{\phold#3}}
> \newcommand*{\envl}{\@ifstar{\@envl{&}}{\@envl{~}}}
> \newcommand*{\@envl}[3]{\@env{#1}{#2}{#3\phold}}
> \newcommand*{\envb}{\@ifstar{\@envb{&}}{\@envb{~}}}
> \newcommand*{\@envb}[4]{\@env{#1}{#2}{#3\phold#4}}
>
> % set environment for feature matrix with square brackets
> \newcommand*{\phonfeat}[1]{%
>   \ensuremath{%
>     \left[\begin{tabular}{c}#1\end{tabular}\right]%
>   }%
> }
> \newcommand*{\oneof}[2][c]{%
>   \ensuremath{%
>     \left\{
>     \begin{tabular}{#1#1}#2\end{tabular}
>     \right.
>   }%
> }
>
> \begin{document}
> \phon{x}{\oneof[l]{ \envr*{w}{z} \\
>       \envl*{v}{\phonfeat{
>       \textplus feature x \\
>       \textminus feature y
> }}}}
>
> \phon{x}{\oneof[l]{
>    \envr{w}{z} \\
>    \envl{v}{\phonfeat{
>    \textplus feature x \\
>    \textminus feature y
> }}}}
>
> \phon{x}{\oneof{
>    \envr{w}{z} \\
>    \envl{v}{\phonfeat{
>    \textplus feature x \\
>    \textminus feature y
> }}}}
>
> \end{document}
> ```
>
> The changes are:
>
> 1. The `\oneof` command accepts an optional argument for the inner alignment, default `c` like in the original; it can be `l` or `r`.
> 2. The commands `\env`, `\envl`, `\envr` and `\envb` have a *-form, which inserts an `&` after `/` instead of the default `~`, so they can be used in the argument of `\oneof` in order to get the alignment you wish.
>
> In the code above I used all three possibilities; the first example is what you're looking for, the second one just has left alignment, the final one is like the original.
>
> [image]